# git describe not showing most recent tag as advertised

Tags: git, git-tag, git-describe

I am on git version 2.40.1

I'm simply looking the get the **most recent** tag number from a given branch. Not the overall latest tag number from the whole repo. Not a random old tag number.

For example,

- the `dev` branch can be on a commit that is tagged 1.3.4
- the `test` branch can be on a commit that is tagged 1.2.9
- the `master` branch can be on a commit that is tagged 1.1.2

I want to be able to checkout `master` branch, get the most recent tag would return me 1.1.2.

If I switch to be on `test` branch, getting the most recent tag would return me 1.2.9

Reading from [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe/2.42.0), `git describe` says: "The command finds the **most recent** tag that is reachable from a commit."

My local repo is on branch `test`. I just created a new tag after merging from a dev branch (tag 6.16.15). But when I do `git describe` is gives me a **very** old tag number (6.6.10-1137-gb5a1f2d). I know I can use the --abbrev=0 to chop off the useless suffix, but even then, the tag number is not the **most recent** one.

`git describe --tags` give me the right tag number.

`git describe` does not give me the **most recent** tag.

Why is the git documentation lying?

Though the `git describe --tags` seems to work in my case, I feel uneasy to use an additional parameter when the documentation says that I should get what I am looking for without the `--tags` parameter. Am I just being lucky?... I need to be sure of what is going on here because I am going to program this in install scripts and I need to be sure I am installing the **most recent** tag number from a given branch.

Comment: The documentation says that `--tags` also matches on “lightweight” tags. Normally it only matches on annotated tags. That could explain the difference.

Comment: As to why you have this distinction between tags? Dunno. They could have just used another ref namespace for what “lightweight tags” are used for now.

Comment: @Guildenstern Thank you for you input. I create tags in GitLab and when I leave the "message" field empty, it becomes a lightweight tag (I just learned that...). So by giving the `--tags` parameter to the command I make sure to include all tags in the lookup. This way I will receive always the most recent tag whether they are lightweight or annotated. I feel that this should be the default (without the --tags parameter) but who am I...

Comment: You aren't the first to raise this concern and I think that it is a reasonable one. The idea behind it seems to be that annotated tags are interesting for `git describe` since they are often versions of the repository, while lightweight tags can be used for things like temporary “bookmarks” (what I would personally call them—put them in `refs/bookmarks` instead).

Answer (score 1):

[`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) without any option arguments will only show *annotated tags*:

> By default (without --all or --tags) git describe only shows annotated tags. For more information about creating annotated tags see the -a and -s options to `git tag`.

If you want to use *any tags* (including lightweight tags) in the describe output, specify `--tags`:

> Instead of using only the annotated tags, use any tag found in `refs/tags` namespace. This option enables matching a lightweight (non-annotated) tag.